# Get value child returning null cloud function real time database

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to get the key of this child, but its returning null and how to store {users_uid} into const or variable? 
I dont know whats wrong here.

```
const uid_tugas = admin.database().ref('/user_course/{users_uid}/' + course_id);
             if (uid_tugas != null){
                uid_tugas.once('value').then(snap6 =>{
                    const uid_tugas_val = snap6.val();
                    console.log(`value uidnya`+ uid_tugas_val.course_id);

                }).catch(error =>{
                    console.log(error);
                })
             }
             else{
                console.log(`tidak ada`);
             }
```

database structure
[image]

This is my full function code

```
export const onNotifTugas = functions.database.ref('/tugas_course/{course_id}/{tugas_id}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{


    const course_id = context.params.course_id;
    const tugas_id = context.params.tugas_id;

    const authVar = context.auth;
    const timestamp = context.timestamp;
    const messageID = context.params.messageID;
    console.log(`MID ${messageID} in ${timestamp}`);


    return admin.database().ref('/tugas/' + tugas_id +'/').once('value').then(snap => {
            const tugasData = snap.val();
            const notifDataSend = { // buat structure data json dgn nama const notifDataSend untul cloud messaging
                data: {
                            data_type: "tugas",
                            title: "Anda mendapatkan notifikasi baru..", // data bebas (key, value)
                            body: `Tugas ${tugasData.nama_tugas} baru`, // chatId = const chatId
                            sound: "default"
                      }
             };

             const uid_tugas = admin.database().ref('/user_course/{users_uid}/' + course_id);
             if (uid_tugas != null){
                uid_tugas.once('value').then(snap6 =>{
                    const uid_tugas_val = snap6.val();
                    console.log(`value uidnya`+ uid_tugas_val.course_id);

                }).catch(error =>{
                    console.log(error);
                })
             }
             else{
                console.log(`tidak ada`);
             }




            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(course_id, notifDataSend) 
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
              })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
              });

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `authVar` is your authentication reference, your `uid` will be `authVar.uid`. Then you can write your `uid_tugas` assignment like so:

```js
const users_uid = authVar.uid;    
const uid_tugas = admin.database().ref('/user_course/' + users_uid + '/' + course_id)
```

You can check out the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Comment: My uid stored at user_course. that possible to get uid to users that receive the notification?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Would you mind clarifying? Do you mean you would like to send the list of courses for each user to be sent to them?

Comment: I want to store the uid to new ref when users receive the notification. actually,only get user uid who receive this notification

Comment: So you're trying to create a ref with a list of all uids that received the notification?